# No serializer found when serializing one Object

Tags: java, json, spring, objectmapper

I'm trying to return an Object as JSON. 
Using the `/user/id` endpoint, I want to display a User based on his Id. 
When calling this controllerMethod I get the following Exception:

```
InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.sample.scrumboard.models.User_$$_jvsta02_1["handler"])
```

My contollerClass looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/user")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserRestController {

    private UserRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public UserRestController(UserRepository repository){
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/list")
    public List<User> getUsers(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public @ResponseBody User getUserById(@PathVariable Long id, User user){
            user = repository.getOne(id);
            return user;
    }
}
```

I checked if al fields have a public getter and tried various options with @JSONIgnoreProperties, but I can't find it.
Displaying all users as a JSONlist does work JSONlist with `/user/list`. So the problem is only there when trying to display one Object, not a list of Objects.
From the repository it does find the User, but it's unable to serialize that Object and put in on the screen.

The User class itself looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userId", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=20)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=20)
    private String userName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String passWord;

    @NotNull
    @Email
    private String email;

    //the mappedBy element must be used to specify the relationship field or property of the entity that is the owner of the relationship
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<UserStory> userStoryList;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String userName, String passWord, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.passWord = passWord;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                ", passWord='" + passWord + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassWord() {
        return passWord;
    }

    public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
        this.passWord = passWord;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<UserStory> getUserStoryList() {
        return userStoryList;
    }

    public void setUserStoryList(List<UserStory> userStoryList) {
        this.userStoryList = userStoryList;
    }
}
```

How can I display my User returned from `/user/id`?

**A Solution?**

As suggested below, I made it work using a Dto and ModelMapper.

I added

```
@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper(){
    return new ModelMapper();
}
```

ControllerMethod

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
public UserDTO getUserById(@PathVariable Long id, User user, ModelMapper modelMapper){
        user = repository.getOne(id);
        return modelMapper.map(user, UserDTO.class);
}
```

And UserDto

```
public class UserDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
    private String passWord;
    private String email;
    private List<UserStory> userStoryList;
    //getters and setters
```

Now I'm able to show a User on the screen.
Still I'm wondering if there is no solution using Jackson and without modelmapper and dto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's not a good idea to use your entity (User) to expose the data about user via REST? Can you create UserDTO for your user that will implement Serializable and send this DTO via REST? In this case it should be necessary to convert User object that you've retrieved from the db to UserDTO.

Comment: Ok I'll try it that way. But shouldn't Jackson be able to do this for me without having to create my own ModelMapper?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot answer because I have very limited experience with Spring (I'm working primarily with Java EE). But as far as I know it is a rule of thumb that REST should not expose entities from DB but DTOs you have control over.

Comment: *it is a rule of thumb*. No, it's matter of opinion that often seems to be presented  as a statement of fact.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following line to your application.properties file :

`spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` in the controller class.

Use the below annotation in the entity class. That solved that issue.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties` should not be on `UserRestController`, what you need to serialize is `User`, remove annotation  is just ok. Jackson will help to do all the work, if you want to ignore some fields on class `User`, move `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to User class, and add `@JsonProperty` on filed need to display on the page.

Comment: Ok. And I still have to create a DTO then?

Answer (score 0):

Serializability of your orm classes implementing the java.io.Serializable interface

You are using @RestController, there is no need of @ResponseBody

Also there is no need to create a DTO class to transform the ORM class for the response json.

OBS: For the Bidirectional reationship you will use @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference

Answer (score 0):

There is a different between spring repository.getOne() and repository.findById(). With getOne() you can get a reference (proxy) e.g. if the object is already read in the same transaction. With findById() you always get the User as expected.

Answer (score 0):

i am apply the
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
in my cause . it was not working fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).